# polars - memory allocation of N bytes failed

Tags: python, python-polars

Trying to execute a statement on a file of 30 Gbs containing 26 million records with 33 columns. When we execute on a sample with 10,000 rows, works without any errors. problem exists on the full file. Noticed that I was able to execute the code in jupyter, however this fails when running from VS Code on Windows 10 64 bit.

```py
       df = (
            df
            .groupby([person_id_key, person_source_id_key, "person_source_type"])
            .agg(
                [
                    # All Names
                    pl.concat_list(
                        pl.col(full_name_key).fill_null(""),
                        pl.col(nickname_key).fill_null("").str.split("|"),
                        pl.col(first_name_key).fill_null("") + " " + pl.col(last_name_key).fill_null("")
                    )
                    .arr.eval(pl.element().filter(~pl.element().is_in(special_removal)))
                    .flatten()
                    .unique()
                    .alias("name"),

                    # All Companies
                    pl.concat_list(org_name_key, master_org_name_key)
                    .flatten()
                    .unique()
                    .alias("company")
                ]
            )
            .with_columns(pl.col('name').arr.lengths().alias("size_of_name"))
            .filter(
                pl.col("size_of_name") >= 1
            )
            .drop(["size_of_name"])
        )
```

is it a problem with my script or should I try a different version of polars than 0.17.2?

Let me know in comments if there is any other information that will be helpful, the dataset is confidential but I can share a synthetic version if necessary.

Comment: Updated version has been posted to github - https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8188

Comment: "Problem exists only from vs code on windows 64 bit windows 10 machine.": that seems pretty important information to have in the question.